# How are light weight threads scheduled by the linux kernel on a multichip multicore SMP system?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, scheduler, smp, lightweight-processes

I am running a parallel algorithm using light threads and I am wondering how are these assigned to different cores when the system provides several cores and several chips. Are threads assigned to a single chip until all the cores on the chip are exhausted? Are threads assigned to cores on different chips in order to better distribute the work between chips?

Comment: Which threading library are you using?

Comment: Is that behaviour library dependent? Thought those details where handled by the kernel scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what OS you're on, but in Linux, threads are assigned to a core based on the load on that core. A thread that is ready to run will be assigned to a core with lowest load unless you specify otherwise by setting thread affinity. You can do this with `sched_setaffinity()`. See the man page for more details. In general, as meyes1979 said, this is something that is decided by the scheduler implemented in the OS you are using.

Depending upon the version of Linux you're using, there are two articles that might be helpful: [this article describes early 2.6 kernels, up through 2.6.22](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scheduler/), and [this article describes kernels newer than 2.6.23](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, the OS is linux.

Comment: Let me see if I am getting this: a thread is assigned to the core with the lowest load but you can set a thread affinity to "suggest" a core. Now, I thought a thread was usually assigned to the core it was already running in to avoid cache misses. So, if that is the case, the thread tries to remain on the core it started to work in but if the core is busy, then it may "migrate" to a different one to load balance. Am I missing something?

Comment: You've got it right. I would suggest digging through the Linux source if you have it handy, particularly `kernel/sched.c`. I'm looking at 2.6.32. Every timer tick, the scheduler will be invoked (`scheduler_tick()`). When it is, the scheduler will check to see if there is a significant load imbalance among the cores (`trigger_load_balance()`). `load_balance()` will eventually be called, which is where the decisions you're interested in are made.

Answer (score 0):

Different threading libraries perform threading operations differently. The "standard" in Linux these days is [NPTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPTL), which schedules threads at the same level as processes. This is quite fine, as process creation is fast on Linux, and is intended to always remain fast.

The Linux kernel attempts to provide very strong CPU affinity with executing processes and threads to increase the ratio of cache hits to cache misses -- if a task always executes on the same core, it'll more likely have pre-populated cache lines.

This is usually a good thing, but I have noticed the kernel might not always migrate tasks away from busy cores to idle cores. This behavior is liable to change from version to version, but I have found multiple CPU-bound tasks all running on one core while three other cores were idle. (I found it by noticing that one core was six or seven degrees Celsius warmer than the other three.)

In general, the right thing should just happen; but when the kernel does not automatically migrate tasks to other processors, you can use the `taskset(1)` command to restrict the processors allowed to programs or you could modify your program to use the `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)` function to ask for individual threads to be migrated. (This is perhaps best for in-house applications -- one of your users might not *want* your program to use all available cores. If you do choose to include calls to this function within your program, make sure it is configurable via configuration files to provide functionality similar to the `taskset(1)` program.)

Comment: good point on Linux keeping the caches warm (apparently in a literal sense as well). [Here](http://littledaemons.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/cpu-affinity-and-taskset/) is another discussion of this for OP's reference.